# Unable to vertically align a label and a button

Tags: html, css

Please excuse me if the question may sound silly, hoping that it will be helpful to someone else.

I'm trying to have my buttons well aligned with a given label. Unfortunately, I am quite not very successful, since despite the same height and padding values, the various elements are not aligned on the vertical plane as I would like them to be.

What I basically did is to copy the CSS bits that I have for my label `.resizedTextbox` and pasted them in those of my buttons `button`.

Does any one have the same issue or what am I missing here?

```css
.resizedTextbox {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-color: #3e12cc;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #154682;
  background-color: #f5effb;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="section">
  <h2>Trying to align buttons and label</h2>
  <div id="home_automation_tab">
    <p></p>
    <td class="tablerows"><input id="lab91" type="text" name="country" class="resizedTextbox" value="0" readonly>
      <button class="button">Off</button>
      <button class="button">30%</button>
      <button class="button">50%</button>
      <button class="button">80%</button>
      <button class="button">On</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **Flexbox**

Also no need to write `padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px`...just use `padding: 5px` if values for top, right, bottom, left are same.

And also remove `<td class="tablerows">` from your code..no need here

```css
#home_automation_tab {
  display: flex;
}

.resizedTextbox {
  width: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-color: #3e12cc;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #154682;
  background-color: #f5effb;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 80px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="section">
  <h2>Trying to align buttons and label</h2>
  <div id="home_automation_tab">
    <p></p>
    <input id="lab91" type="text" name="country" class="resizedTextbox" value="0" readonly>
    <button class="button">Off</button>
    <button class="button">30%</button>
    <button class="button">50%</button>
    <button class="button">80%</button>
    <button class="button">On</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Also your code is working fine as it written..you will need to use `box-sizing: border-box` for both `button` and `label` and try to change the value of height so that the content get visible

```css
.resizedTextbox {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-color: #3e12cc;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #154682;
  background-color: #f5effb;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="section">
  <h2>Trying to align buttons and label</h2>
  <div id="home_automation_tab">
    <p></p>
    <input id="lab91" type="text" name="country" class="resizedTextbox" value="0" readonly>
    <button class="button">Off</button>
    <button class="button">30%</button>
    <button class="button">50%</button>
    <button class="button">80%</button>
    <button class="button">On</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bhuwan. Your quick help has been much appreciated. Have a very good week-end. Kind regards, Laurent

Comment: @Laurent Glad it helped you...!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem. **The flexbox answer above by Bhuwan is probably the best way to go.**

If you are stuck with the HTML structure and just wanted a css solution, do the following:

- Be sure to copy `vertical-align:text-top` to both css classes
- Add `box-sizing: border-box` to each (I used the wildcard selector below,
  but you can just add it to each).
- And set the height exactly. You previously were relying on the border, plus padding, plus font-size, etc to set the height of each element.
- You may also have to revisit the width of your label at this point but here you have complete pixel control over the height and width of each element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.resizedTextbox {
  width: 40px; 
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-color:#3e12cc;
  text-shadow:0px 1px 1px #154682;
  background-color:#f5effb;
  vertical-align:text-top;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:18px;
}

.button {
  border-radius:3px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size:18px;
  vertical-align:text-top;
}
```

```html
 <div id="section">
  <h2>Trying to align buttons and label</h2>
  <div id="home_automation_tab">
    <p></p>
    <td class="tablerows">
      <input id="lab91" type="text" name="country" class="resizedTextbox" value="0" readonly>
      <button class="button">Off</button>
      <button class="button">30%</button>
      <button class="button">50%</button>
      <button class="button">80%</button>
      <button class="button">On</button>
     </td>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: One thousand thanks wlh. Your help on this has been much appreciated. Have a great week-end. Kind regards, Laurent